# How can I get HTTP response header using JS?

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

I tried so many tutorials online but everything I try is really old and fails - I can't even create an XMLHTTPRequest object!

I just want to get the header from google.com - how can I do that?

Comment: Making a request to google is going to violate the cross host restriction.  You cannot request a page on a hostname other than your site's.  (Though you can do so in round about ways -- just not with a XMLHTTPRequestObject.)

Comment: "Really old"? What have you tried? What "tutorials"? Which actual, proper, peer-reviewed _books_ are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `xhr.getResponseHeader()` to get a single header, or `xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()` to read all of the headers from an `XMLHttpRequest` response.

The reasons this won't work for you:

- `XMLHttpRequest` is case sensitive.  If you are using `HTTP` in all caps, it will fail.
- Unless you are a google employee adding code to google.com, your request falls victim to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  You'll have to use your server as a proxy to get headers from a google request.

Answer (score 0):

You cant simply do this by JS. You'll have to use AJAX and do a server request to PHP,ASP, Java or whatever. The XMLHTTPRequest should do it - if you really want to do it manually. But it will really not work with foreign domains, so you are forced to do the XMLHTTTPRequest to a page on your server which will deliver the header.